# not able to install SSDT for visual studio 2017 professional

Tags: database, data-warehouse, sql-data-warehouse

Need your help

I have successfully installed VS2017 on my computer .

But when I tried to install SQL server data tools 15.6.0 or 15.5.1 it gives me error as below :
Setup failed 
The configuration registry key could not be opened(0x800703F3)

Thanks All!!

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the installer: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246732/ssdt-1560-installer-the-configuration-registry-key.html

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (15.6) of SSDT is incompatible with the latest version (15.7) of Visual Studio 2017. You currently have two choices:

1. Wait for an updated version of SSDT or VS2017 to be released, or
2. Completely uninstall VS2017 and install an older version.

If you want to go with option 2, do the following:

1. Run this command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe -f`
2. Download and install version 15.6.7 of Visual Studio ([link to the Community edition](https://aka.ms/eac464))
3. Download and install [SSDT 15.6.0](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=871368)

This info was taken from [a post on the Visual Studio Developer Community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/239580/setup-failed-error-while-installing-ssdt-to-vs-201.html).