# SSDT Installation for VS2017 Team Explorer Fails

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, team-explorer

I am attempting to install SSDT v15.6.0 into an existing Visual Studio Team Explorer 2017 instance. When I run the SSDT installer, I can select Visual Studio Team Explorer 2017 from this list of existing Visual Studio instances. If I do not choose a any options (other than the required SQL Server Database option). The installation completes successfully.

If I however attempt to pick any/all of the other options the installation fails. From looking at the log files, it appears that the installation of the VSIX is failing due to a required component missing.

Below is the snippet of the SSDT-Setup installation log file which indicates that the VSIX failed to install.

```
[167C:1A6C][2018-05-16T15:40:41]i301: Applying execute package: Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\VSIXBootstrapper.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\VSIXBootstrapper.exe" /q /admin /instanceIds:"68f392fc" /logFile:"C:\Users\golaat\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtSetup\SSDT-Setup-ENU_20180516153141_009_Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.log" "payload\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.vsix"'
[167C:1A6C][2018-05-16T15:41:13]e000: Error 0x80131500: Process returned error: 0x80131500
[167C:1A6C][2018-05-16T15:41:13]e000: Error 0x80131500: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1D80:1858][2018-05-16T15:41:13]e000: Error 0x80131500: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
```

Looking at the log file for the installation of the VSIX it seems like a required component is missing:

```
 5/16/2018 3:41:05 PM - BEGIN: Targetting Visual Studio Team Explorer 2017,15.0.27428.2043
 5/16/2018 3:41:05 PM - BEGIN: Execute batch install
 5/16/2018 3:41:08 PM - BEGIN: Preparing extension Microsoft Integration Services Projects
 5/16/2018 3:41:08 PM - Loading extension: Microsoft Integration Services Projects
 5/16/2018 3:41:10 PM - JSON file loaded
 5/16/2018 3:41:10 PM - The dependent package of 'Component.D1B09713-C12E-43CC-9EF4-6562298285AB,version=1.4' cannot be found: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=[15.0,16.0).
 5/16/2018 3:41:10 PM - END: Execute batch install
 5/16/2018 3:41:10 PM - END: Installing
 5/16/2018 3:41:10 PM - Common folder deleted: C:\Users\golaat\AppData\Local\Temp\s0ggmkmo.cwz
 5/16/2018 3:41:10 PM - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyGraphConstructionException: The dependent package of 'Component.D1B09713-C12E-43CC-9EF4-6562298285AB,version=1.4' cannot be found: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=[15.0,16.0).
```

Is there a way to identify this missing component an perhaps install it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of SSDT 15.7.1, Team Explorer no longer shows up as an existing Visual Studio install instance option within SSDT. At first I was concerned that the SSDT install would install a Visual Studio shell with no TFS connectivity, however this was not the case. It appears that the SSDT install of the Visual Studio shell picks up on the fact that Visual Studio Team Explorer 2017 is already installed on the machine and the SSDT Visual Studio shell instance has full TFS Connectivity!

Answer (score 17):

This is how I fixed it :

1. Run installer normally to the end and let it fail.
2. When it fails the window will have a link to the log file, open it.
3. In this log file, 1 or 2 lines before the error(Process returned error: 0x80131500) problem component location will be revealed, something like this:

> [6748:674C][2020-07-29T09:44:03]i301: Applying execute package:
> ISVsix, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache\15160B731819F56D87A626F9A2777550340022D7\VSIXBootstrapper.exe,
> arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache\15160B731819F56D87A626F9A2777550340022D7\VSIXBootstrapper.exe"
> /q /admin /instanceIds:"5403e431"
> /logFile:"C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20200729093525_11_ISVsix.log"
> "payload\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.vsix"

You have to combine location of the VSIXBootstrapper with vsix component location. In my case I had vsix file under C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\15160B731819F56D87A626F9A2777550340022D7\payload

4. Copy failing component(.vsix), in this case Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.vsix to some folder before it gets deleted. If it already got deleted then restart the installer and search for this component in parent folders.
5. Restart your computer. I was getting "Another installation running .." error before I did.
6. Go to the folder where you copied the failing component and install the .vsix manually. This time it should install normally.
7. Repeat step 1 but this time hoping it will work normally.

I hope this at least gets you in the right direction.

Comment: I actually used your answer here to fix the issue with the install for the VS2019 install.  Pulled most of my hair out here, but it is working thanks to your direction.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, MelOS! Your recipe worked like a charm!

Comment: Brilliant! Wish I could upvote more.  My process wasn't exact, I had to task kill the install after copying the vsix and I didn't need to reboot.  Also, when I ran the vsix manually it said it was installed already.  But after this when I ran the installer it completed without error and I was able to open an existing SSIS project in VS2019 after.  Would not have got there without this solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you!  I went to install SSIS 3.15 and ran into this error message.  However I was able to run the install, let it fail.  Re-run the installer and force close whatever it complained about, then re-run the installer with no issues. However I did see the folders you were describing in the programdata folder.  Excellent find!

Comment: Than you so much. This is still an issue with SSIS 3.15 and VS 2019. In addition to the .vsix file, the log complained about two missing folders which I created and ended up having a successful installation.

Comment: Great answer! A tip for others using this solution - I found that the VSIX wasn't on the filesystem for very long, so I opened a file explorer at `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` and started the installer. As soon as it hit the "installing" stage, I copy-pasted out the (three) folders that the installer had created, then found the VSIX from within the copy, and ran it once the main installer had failed.

Comment: You should charge people for this answer. Pure gold, thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is currently broken due to a bug in Visual Studio - see this post on the Developer Community site:
[SSDT cannot install onto 15.7 version of Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/254066/ssdt-cannot-install-onto-157-version-of-visual-stu.html)

It'll be fixed in a forthcoming Visual Studio update, but if you can't wait for that a workaround is to completely uninstall Visual Studio and install an older version. See my answer here for instructions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50349464/1184850

Comment: I updated my Visual Studio Team Explorer to 15.7.2 and still have the same problem. Attempting to install into the Team Explorer instance results in the error described above. Selecting the option to install into a new Visual Studio stand-alone instance results in the setup program displaying an "Incorrect function (0x800070001) error.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, follow these steps:

1. Download SQL Server and install it. In the **Feature Selection** step install **Integration Service**

[image]

2. Now download Visual Studio installer and install **.NET desktop development** and **Data storage and processing**

[image]

3. Now run Visual Studio and go to Extensions > Manage Extensions > Online, and search for SQL Server Integration Services Projects. Download and install that

[image]

You are now good to go.