# Can't install SSRS or SSIS package from SQL Server Data Tools package onto Visual Studio 2017

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, visual-studio-2017, installation, sql-server-data-tools

SSDT was installed through the Visual Studio 2017 installer, but didn't include Analysis Services, Reporting Services or Integration Services tooling. I downloaded the latest SQL Server Data Tools installer and tried installing, but only Analysis Services installed. Both SSRS and SSIS fail. Both give:

> "Unknown Error 0x80131509).

I've tried several times, rebooted, re-downloaded, nothing worked. If I uninstall SSDT, VS installer will remove many other components, so didn't want to do that without seeing if someone had a solution.

Help?!

Thanks!

End of the log file shows this:

```
Error 0x80131509: Process returned error: 0x80131509
Error 0x80131509: Failed to execute EXE package.
Error 0x80131509: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package SQL Server Reporting Services (id: Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices)
Applied execute package: Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices, result: 0x80131509, restart: None
Error 0x80131509: Failed to execute EXE package.
Removed package dependency provider: Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices, package: Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices
Removing cached package: Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\
Removed dependency: {f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87} on package provider: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, package Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices
MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package SQL Server Analysis Services (id: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices)
MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall progress: 15
Applying rollback package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\VSIXBootstrapper.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\VSIXBootstrapper.exe" /q /admin /instanceIds:"18a2cbc4" /logFile:"C:\Users\sspotts\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtSetup\SSDT-Setup-ENU_20180522091154_000_Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.log" /u:04a86fc2-dbd5-4222-848e-911638e487fe'
Error 0x80070003: Failed to CreateProcess on path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\VSIXBootstrapper.exe
Error 0x80070003: Failed to execute EXE package.
Error 0x80070003: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package SQL Server Analysis Services (id: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices)
Applied rollback package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, result: 0x80070003, restart: None
Removed package dependency provider: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices
Removing cached package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\
Unable to remove cached package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\, reason: 0x80070003. Continuing...
MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall progress: 100
Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
Removed bundle dependency provider: {f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87}
Removing cached bundle: {f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87}\
Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: Unknown error (0x80131509) (0x80131509)
Apply complete, result: 0x80131509, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\sspotts\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtSetup\SSDT-Setup-ENU_20180522091154.log
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. I've recreated on a fresh Windows Server 2016 VM with the latest releases of Visual Studio 2017 17.2 Community and SSDT 15.6.0. I believe this has to do with their attempted [fix of the registry error from before.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246732/ssdt-1560-installer-the-configuration-registry-key.html)

Comment: Looks like it is related to the permissions issue.

Comment: I'm a local admin, running the install in an admin context.

Comment: can you show in the log what was going on just before the error message? That might help.

Comment: [I answered a similar question here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63167815/3921617)

Comment: [I answered a similar question here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63167815/3921617)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [Download Data-Tier Application Framework (DacFx) 17.4.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56508)
before installing the SSDT. This will fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

More information will be needed to diagnose the issue. Please,

1. Download and run https://aka.ms/vscollect
2. Oen an issue on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com
3. Attach %TEMP%\vslogs.zip from the first step

Answer (score 1):

In a cmd window, browse to the folder with the downloaded setup exe.

Then run

```
SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /layout

cd payload

Microsoft.DataTools.*.VSIX
```

Replace the asterisk in the last command with the modules you want to install and that are located in the payload folder.

e.g.

```
Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.VSIX
Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.VSIX
Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices.VSIX
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my biggest pet-peeve with SSDT on VS2017 - I have been using it since it was in Preview. Uninstall SSDT completely and reinstall it. See the link below and look at the accepted answer. You will need to perform some manual intervention after the installer runs its uninstall - ignore the warning about putting your computer in an unusable state.

[visual studio (SSDT) 2017 unable to start debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780661/visual-studio-ssdt-2017-unable-to-start-debugging)

Note: Whenever an update for SSDT/VS2017 comes out, they install fine. But, for some reason (and I don't know why), SSAS and SSRS have their own separate updates. In order to install them, you have to first uninstall the existing SSAS/SSRS installations (Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Tools). I failed to do this one time for SSAS and had the pleasure of reinstalling both SSDT and VS2017. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing SSDT **15.6.0** with Visual Studio 2017 (versions 15.7.2 and 15.7.3). I solved the problem downloading and installing SSDT **15.7.0** (download link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer)).

In SSDT 15.7.0 [changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/changelog-for-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-visual-studio-2017-1570) is mentioned a problem with SSRS and SSIS installation, so probably there was an issue in the installer component of versions before 15.7.0.

Here is an excerpt from the changelog regarding an installer-related issue fixed in this release of SSDT:

> Fix an issue that SSAS cannot be installed before SSRS and SSIS are installed in VS 15.7.2.